# how return relational name on foreingkey django

Tags: mysql, django

how i can return the name from the model relational :

```
code:
Inactive = 0
Active = 1

state_choices = (
    (Inactive, 'Inactive'),
    (Active, 'Active')
)
class Tipe(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.IntegerField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=state_choices,
        default=Active,
    )

class People(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=9, null=True)
    state = models.IntegerField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=state_choices,
        default=Active,
    )
    tipe = models.ForeignKey(Tipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

the question is how i can return tipe.name from model Tipe when i run this:

```
People.objects.all().filter(state=1)
```

this case only return the foreingkey dont the name from my model relational. maybe any suggest please.. thanks

Comment: This does *not* return the *foreign key*. It simply returns *all* `People` with `state=1`, the `Tipe` is not taken into account at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p = People.objects.all().filter(state=1)
# p.tipe.name
names = [x.tipe.name for x in p]
```

Comment: on this case return only the first... thanks.. but the idea is return all rows from table People... with the name tipe...

Comment: i change for p=People.objects.all() and whe i try p.tipe.name say 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'tipe'

Comment: @Tegito123 `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'tipe` because it is `QuerySet` object(list of your instances) not Instance of `People`. You need to do a loop over the queryset and call `p.tipe.name` on each iteration.